# Showing error on ng serve while trying to run the project

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

Iam new to angular.I installed the latest Node.js and installed Angular CLI globally. I just cloned the project from github and tried to run the angular project using ng serve but it is showing me error:

[image]

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "my-dream-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  }
}
```

I dont know what is being mismatched and how can I match the angualr CLI with the cloned project?

Comment: This project doesn't seem to use the Angular CLI. Ask the project maintainer(s) how to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you just downloaded/cloned it from github and tried to run it immediately?
If so, you might have forgotten to run "npm install", this installs the necessary libraries for the github-project.

Greetings Agren

Comment: it showed me Cannot find module @angular/compiler-cli/ngcc

Comment: it works for some project bt doesnt works for some project why is it so ?

Comment: could be a range of things, so i can't pin point the exact problem for all of them or give you a better explanation, sorry @AshwinKarki